# why did memcache get expired everyday whereas i have set it to 0 as expiration time?

Tags: php, memcached

I dont know why is this happening. Everytime i set data like this-

```
    $mem = new Memcache();
    $mem->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");     
    $userData=$mem->get("$USERID_DATA");
    if(!empty($userData)){
        $DATA=$userData;
        echo "COMMING FROM HOME";
    } else {
        $DATA=$modelUser->getUserData($USERID);
        $mem->set("$USERID_DATA",$DATA,MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED,0); // Never Expired
        echo "COMMING FROM MOON";
    }
    var_dump($DATA);
```

and next when i returned to see my data after login ..
it printed all the data, but it gives me message `COMMING FROM MOON`

It means it gives me data from DB not from memcache.

Am i doing something wrong?

Please help..

Comment: can be a problem on empty($userData) test. try to var_dump $userData before

Comment: yes i have checked before storing .. $userData it is fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you restart the machine the `memcache daemon` will go down and start again, resulting in loosing the stored data as `memcached` is an in memory store. So your previously stored data will not be there when you restart the machine.

Comment: how is this possible i had started just PC, not Server.

Comment: @user3553297: when u shutdown ur system and start it again, the memcached instance running on it will also go down. Hope you understand it. From your code u connect to `localhost` only not any remote memcached instance.

Comment: I can only say "Thanks".